# Adafruit trinket + acceleleometer + low power transmitter

Tags: arduino

I need to make a device where there has to be the following components:
1. An accelerometer chip ( as thin and small as possible)
2. A bluetooth or low power data transmitter

The device will be attached to an object and if the object is moved in a certain way, a small amount of data needs to be transmitted indicating that the object has moved.

Restriction: The whole device has to be as thin as possible. 
The transmitter can be low powered because the receiver will be within a few feet(4-5 feet). The amount of data transmitted is also very small (a few bytes).

Can you guys give me a suggestion what are the devices I can use? 
I am thinking about an MPU-6050 3-Axis Gyroscope + 3-Axis Accelerometer 6-DOF Module (Arduino Compatible Core Module) and an adafruit trinket. But I do not know what module I can use to trasmit the data.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hardware design.

Comment: I have submitted the question in electronics.stackexchange.com. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
http://www.aliexpress.com/item/nrf51822-MPU6050-6pixs/32456095618.html?ws_ab_test=201407_1%2C201444_6_3_2_1_5_4%2C201409_1&spm=2114.01020208.3.2.MJWube

It is a module with Bluetooth (nRF51822)/6-DOF Gyroscope/Accelerometer as well as a wireless charging module. The size is only 16 mm and the module is super thin.

I used this for my project and worked very well.
A lot of tools can be used for programming it like MK20 USB from redbearlab or just nRF51822-mKIT.